# History of Math and Science proposal is in commit stage

Tags: discussion, area51

This is to announce that the History of Math and Science StackExchange proposal on Area 51 has entered the "commit" stage. You can read more about the proposal [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/area-51-proposal-history-of-mathematics-and-science) and see the proposal itself [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65204/history-of-science-and-mathematics/).

In the commitment stage, a certain number of users must "commit" to using the site, which is simply a pledge to use it when the beta launches. Once enough people have done this, the beta version of the site will launch.

Here are some of the top mathematics example questions on the proposal:

- What is the earliest reference for the Prime Number Theorem (as a conjecture)? And, what were earlier or opposing believes regarding this question?
- Was the introduction of higher-dimensional spaces controversial, like the introduction of complex numbers?
- Which attempts were made to formalize differentiation and integration before the modern limit definition?